# How do I parse text to a link in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, tags

I am working on the normal rails blog app, I need to add a tag feature (the same tag as every social media uses).

Example of post: "I love #dogs". What I need to do is to display the tag `#dogs` as a `link_to dogs_path`. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show us your current code, what have your tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to scan the string and extract hastags

#### example

```
source = 'Lets #go to the #gym #today'

hashes = source.scan /\B#[á-úÁ-Úä-üÄ-Üa-zA-Z0-9_]+/

puts hashes
```

see it at [replit](https://repl.it/repls/CaringCompetitiveTexts)

#### create a helper method

```
class SocialHelper
  def linked_content(source)
    hashes = string.scan(/\B#[á-úÁ-Úä-üÄ-Üa-zA-Z0-9_]+/)
    hashes.each do |hash|
      source.gsub!(hash, hash_link(hash)
    end
    source
  end

  def hash_link(hash)
    link_to hashes_path(hash)
  end
end
```

#### view

```
<%= linked_content(post.content) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a link out of text with this ERB in your HTML file: `<%= link_to "#dogs", dogs_path %>`

Where the string immediately following the `link_to` is the string that will be populated as text on the page (a hyperlink).

For your case, you could do something like:

```
<p>I love <%= link_to "#dogs", dogs_path %>.</p>
```